# WCF Services Authorisation to a service function without membership provider

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-identity

I've a WCF service which uses UserNamePasswordValidator for authantication. I check the username and password. If it is ok, then I allow to access service call.

```
class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    WebServiceDM entity = new WebServiceDM();

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {

        string encrypted = CryptographyManager.EncryptSymmetric(password);



        Kullanici _user = entity
                          .Kullanici
                          .FirstOrDefault(h => h.Username == userName && h.Password == encrypted);



        if (_user == null || _user.Username == "")
        {
            //Invalid User ...
            throw new Exception("Username and password failed");
        }


    }

}
```

Now I need a function based Authorisation like **PrincipalPermission**. But in this case, I don't have any Membership provider.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEglenceServices
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<EGLENCEBEYAN> GetEglenceBeyan(int yil);

}
```

So what can I do for this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wire in a custom principal permission, you can use a custom IAuthorizationPolicy implementation.  See http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/ for an example.

Comment: Can we use both service cridential based authantication and authorization policies together in WCF Service ?

Comment: Yes.  See http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx for an example.